# Changing font-family from Segoe to Futura (Bulma)

Tags: css, sass, fonts, netlify, bulma

I'm working from a template that uses Bulma and the default font is set to Segoe UI. However, I'm trying to change the default font in headers to futura-pt-bold.

Here is the place in the all.sass file where I am trying to assign the new font-family (the headers are all in div containers with class "content"):

```
@import "~bulma"
.content h1, h2, h3, h4 
  font-family: futura-pt-bold !important
  font-style: normal
```

But it's still picking Segoe UI instead of Futura pt. I've tried "Futura,"  "Futura PT," etc but nothing seems to work.

I am using Firefox and so far am only running the web app locally.

Comment: where's the part that actually defines `future-pt-bold` as available font via a font-face rule?

Comment: I don't know about that part. Might be the problem.

Comment: it might be, so presumably you've now [search and researched](/help/how-to-ask) how to set up a font-face rule?